# Is "a quiz or assignment" correct? If "an" is omitted before "assignment", how can it be?

Tags: indefinite-article

> Students who want to earn a certificate will be asked to verify their identity each time they submit **a quiz or assignment**.

Is "an" omitted before "assignment" there?
If then, how can "an" be omitted there when "a" before "quiz" is different from "an"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the sentence would be like if the article "an" were added:

> Students who want to earn a certificate will be asked to verify their identity each time they submit a quiz or **an** assignment.

The sentence is grammatically correct with or without the **an**: the omission is a form of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29), where a word or phrase that has already occurred in a sentence is omitted the next time it appears.

The ellipsis can occur with **an** even if the previous occurrence is **a**: this is because **a/an** is affected phonetically by the following word, but the meaning and syntactic function are unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer! Thank you for the teaching and helping!